# When could mktime return -1?

Tags: c++, mktime, time.h

I saw this in the [mktime cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime):

> Time since epoch as a std::time_t object on success or -1 if time cannot be represented as a std::time_t object.

And I started wondering when would this happen. Could anyone give an example where `mktime` returned -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `time_t` can only represent a finite interval, at least on
any system I've seen.  If the date you request is outside that
interval (say `tm_year` equal to 250 on a Unix machine with a 32
bit `time_t`), then `mktime` will return -1.